# desectructuracion en js

Tags: javascript, html, email, nodemailer

estoy intentado sacar de un formulario las variables y despues enviar un correo con esa informacion, el codigo es el siguiente :

esto es lo que manda el body por consola

```
body: [Object: null prototype] {
   nombre: 'leo',
   mailForm: '3d2@gma.com',
   telForm: '323',
   preguntas: 'dwe'
 }
```

yo lo intento desestructurar asi

```
const { nombre, mailForm, telForm, preguntas } = body
```

me sale undefined como resultado

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const body = req;
    console.log(body)
    const { nombre, mailForm, telForm, preguntas } = body
    const contenido = `
        <h2>CONSULTA de ${nombre}</h2>
        <h2> ${nombre} ha hecho una consulta </h2> 
        <h2>${nombre} ha querido ponerse en contacto contigo el ${new Date()} </h2> 
        <h2> su telefono es el ${telForm} y su direccion de correo es ${mailForm}</h2>
        <h2> Las preguntas que tiene son: <br> ${
            preguntas
        }</h2>
         `

        ;

    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'mensaje recibido',
      to: "dsd@gmail.com",
      subject: nombre,
      html: contenido,
    });

});
```

Comment: este es el urlencoded `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))`

Answer (score 0):

Me habia faltado lucidez, aqui la respuesta si ha alguien mas le pasa.

```
 const { nombre, mailForm, telForm, preguntas } = body.body
```

Comment: Explicalo por favor, sino puede ser que otros no lo entiendan. ¿Te olvidaste que `body` es parte de otro objeto que recibes como resultado o cómo?